# Expired seamoss, need answers

Tags: help

Will expired seamoss harm you? Is it harmful to use?? The gel still looks like when i bought it, and shows no
Signs of decay. But it’s about a week past the expiration date. Just wondering is it bad to use?

Comment: Is this Irish moss? You mention "gel". If it's just standard dried seaweed that you use in brewing, then it will be good for years.

Comment: Does the label actually say "expires", or simply "best before"?  In general, "best before" means just that; there won't actually be anything wrong with it. For many products the date is quite arbitrary, often chosen as one year after manufacturing, to make it easy for the vendors to rotate their stock.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused, I believe you're referring to what I know as Irish Moss- added to the boil and used to help clarify beer. In any case, it won't hurt you, I doubt it could expire..although it may be less effective after some amount of years.

> gel still looks like when i bought it

This threw me off. I'm not sure how your "seamoss" would be in gel form, typically brewing moss is dried crushed little brown chunks, or finely powdered. Is there a link or something you could point me to so I can understand better? Perhaps this is another additive that I'm simply not familiar with.

Comment: no they mean sea moss, you blend it with some other stuff and it becomes a gel, lol i’m looking for the same answer tho :(